# How to group my table for latest date and ID?

Tags: sql, database

I have a table like this:

[image]

I need group this table latest date for every ID.
I mean, I want to get last row every ID. Here is my query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ch.Date,ID FROM dbo.tblrisk AS rk  
    inner join (Select TableIdentity, [Date] from tblCommonHistory ) ch 
    ON ch.TableIDentity = rk.ID order by ID
```

How can I do what I want?

EDIT: This query worked for me:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ch.dt,ID  FROM dbo.tblrisk AS rk  
  inner join (Select TableIdentity, max([Date]) as dt from tblCommonHistory group by TableIdentity) ch ON ch.TableIDentity = rk.ID order by ID
```

Comment: Show us the expected result (given the sample data as above.)

Answer (score 1):

Just use aggregation:

```
select TableIdentity, max([date])
from tblCommonHistory
group by TableIdentity;
```

Your question only mentions one table.  Your query has two; I don't understand the discrepancy.

Comment: The table gets ID value from tblrisk table, Date value from tblCommonHistory table.

Comment: To quote the question:  "I have a table like this:".

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that you have duplicated `TableIdentity` in `tblCommonHistory`, but otherwise you should not be getting multiple dates for the same `ID` from your query.

And also, the only reason to join the 2 tables seems to be that you need to skip those `ID` that are not present in the `tblrisk` (is it what you need to do?)

In that case, I'd suggest

```
SELECT max(ch.Date) AS [Date],ID FROM dbo.tblrisk AS rk  
    inner join tblCommonHistory AS ch ON ch.TableIDentity = rk.ID 
    group by ID order by ID
```